# How to type Chinese by fcitx in texmaker?

Tags: ubuntu, editors, latex, input-method, fcitx

I installed `fcitx-googlepinyin` and `texmaker` in Ubuntu LTS 16.04 using `apt-get install` command. However, I cannot switch to `googlepinyin` in `texmaker`'s editor. As a result, I cannot type Chinese with fcitx system in `texmaker`, while such a problem does not occur when I type Chinese at other places  (e.g. gedit and terminal).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using `fcitx` in `texstudio`. I fixed it for the moment by launching it from the terminal like so:

```
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx texstudio
```

Will check back in and edit if I can figure out how to make it automatic.

Comment: Glad to help! Let me know if you manage to figure out how to make it automatic before I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate the process described by pandahats, you can add the following lines into your startup scripts:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
```

For example: .xprofile for desktop environment or .xinitrc otherwise.
I personally use .xinitrc since I use i3.

If you still can't fix it, you can try execute "qtconfig-qt4" and find the default input method option on the third tab.

For more information, please refer to:

```
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fcitx#Non_desktop_environment
```

Regards.